# Gatsby vs Next.js for SEO important website

Tags: ecommerce

Hey basically I know the drawbacks and benefits of these two frameworks but I didn't find explicit which one is faster and better for SEO.

I'm building an e-commerce website with thousands of products.

Best,

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)